# Installing pre-built Laravel site onto local MAMP server

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, mamp, local

thanks for any help in advance. I am a beginner with Laravel and PHP so please forgive me if I am not even asking the right questions.

I have a pre-built (not by me) Laravel (4) site currently on a dev server that I'm hoping to pull down onto my local machine so that I can tinker around with some CSS for some fine-finishing on the styling.

I have consulted many tutorials for Laravel set-up/config but they all seem to concern fresh Laravel installs, not for previously-built sites.

From what I can tell, Composer is already living in the site directory. I'm not sure if Composer is anything I need to worry about at this point?

So far I have: downloaded site via FTP and installed latest version of MAMP. Preparing to dump the database from phpMyAdmin. I'm basically trying to go about this as if I was dealing with a WP build (which I've done before).

Comment: Is the site stored in a repository by any chance? That would be the best way to do this. However you could download the application as you have, and then you should just run `composer update` locally on your machine (you will need to download it and install it) to ensure everything you need is there

Answer (score 1):

The typical process is thussly:

- git clone (or ftp in your case) the code into your directory
- modify (or make) the `.env` file. Ensure all your local variables are in here for things such as database connection, etc.
- composer install
- npm install<sup>1</sup>
- php artisan migrate
- php artisan db:seed
- gulp<sup>2</sup>

<sub>Footnotes</sub>

- <sup>1</sup> This may not be necessary if you don't use node for JavaScript package management in the project
- <sup>2</sup> This may not be necessary if you don't compile assets such as `sass` or `less` or your `javascript`.

Most of the above is pretty standard, but you may not need to perform all the steps. Hope this helps.